# HTML Form in Laravel 5.6 it gives errors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6 and HTML Form 5.4 when I run the code in the browser it's the same like code.

This is the code:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address');
Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true);
Form::radio('name', 'value', true);
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Output in the browser:

```
Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address'); Form::checkbox('name','value', 
true); Form::radio('name', 'value', true);
```

what is the problem

Comment: Laravel 6? Where did you get it?

Comment: Don't you mean Laravel 5.6?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true) !!}
{!! Form::radio('radio_name', 'value', true) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data